# How do I get yesterday's date using localtime?

Tags: perl, localtime

How do I tweak this to get yesterday's date using localtime?

```
use strict;

sub spGetCurrentDateTime;
print spGetCurrentDateTime;

sub spGetCurrentDateTime {
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime();
my @abbr = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
my $currentDateTime = sprintf "%s %02d %4d", $abbr[$mon], $mday, $year+1900; #Returns => 'Aug 17 2010' 
return $currentDateTime;
}
```

~

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The DST problem can be worked around by taking 3600s from midday today instead of the current time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

sub spGetYesterdaysDate;
print spGetYesterdaysDate;

sub spGetYesterdaysDate {
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime();
my $yesterday_midday=timelocal(0,0,12,$mday,$mon,$year) - 24*60*60;
($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime($yesterday_midday);
my @abbr = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
my $YesterdaysDate = sprintf "%s %02d %4d", $abbr[$mon], $mday, $year+1900;
return $YesterdaysDate;
}
```

In light of the "unspecified" documented behaviour of the strftime solution suggested by Chas, this approach might be better if you're not able to test for expected-but-not-guaranteed results across multiple platforms.

Answer (score 24):

```
use DateTime qw();
DateTime->now->subtract(days => 1);
```

The expression on the second line returns a [`DateTime`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) object.

Comment: It does work, I just tested. Maybe you simply forgot to set the `time_zone` attribute in the constructor, or neglected to call the [`set_time_zone`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime#dt-set_time_zone-tz-) method? Maybe you have an outdated release of the [`DateTime::TimeZone`](https://metacpan.org/release/DateTime-TimeZone) distro?

Answer (score 18):

As tempting as it is to just subtract a day's worth of seconds from the current time, there are times when this will yield the wrong answer (leap seconds, DST, and possibly others).  I find it easier to just let `strftime` (available in the Perl 5 core module [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime)) take care of all of that for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

#2010-03-15 02:00:00
my ($s, $min, $h, $d, $m, $y) = (0, 0, 0, 15, 2, 110);

my $time      = timelocal $s, $min, $h, $d, $m, $y;    
my $today     = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime $time;
my $yesterday = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %T", $s, $min, $h, $d - 1, $m, $y;
my $oops      = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime $time - 24*60*60;
print "$today -> $yesterday -> $oops\n";
```

Comment: So if the 'day' value is less than 1 `strftime` counts backwards day + 1 days into the previous month (and possibly year).  Is this behaviour a documented part of POSIX or is it platform-specific?

Comment: @Grant Mclean It may not be standard in POSIX (or SUS), but it is standard in Perl 5.  The documentation says `arguments are made consistent as though by calling "mktime()" before calling your system's "strftime()"`.

Comment: As a one-liner: `perl -MPOSIX -le '@t=localtime;--$t[3];print strftime "%Y%m%d",@t'`

Comment: This is the only correct solution that i'm aware of now, which uses only standard (core) modules.

Answer (score 6):

use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# These are core modules in Perl 5.10 and newer
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $yesterday = localtime() - ONE_DAY;
say $yesterday->strftime('%b %d %Y');
```

Note that this can go wrong in certain borderline cases, such as the start of daylight saving time.
The following version does behave correct in such cases:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# These are core modules in Perl 5.10 and newer
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $now = localtime();
my $yesterday = $now - ONE_HOUR*($now->hour + 12);
say $yesterday->strftime('%b %d %Y');
```

Alternatively, you can use the DateTime module as described in a different answer.  That is not a core module, though.

Comment: Same DST problem hides under the fancy API.

Comment: Good point, daxim.  I've added a version that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: `Time::Piece` and `Time::Seconds` didn't get added to the core until Perl 5.10 (well 5.9.5, but who uses dev releases?).

Answer (score 5):

Solution suggested by most users is wrong!

```
localtime(time() - 24*60*60)
```

The **worst** thing you can do is to assume that *1 day = 86400* seconds.

Example: Timezone is America/New_York, date is Mon Apr  3 00:30:00 2006

**timelocal** gives us **1144038600**

> localtime(1144038600 - 86400) = Sat Apr  1 23:30:00 EST 2006

oops!

The right and the only solution is to let system function normalize values

```
$prev_day = timelocal(0, 0, 0, $mday-1, $mon, $year);
```

Or let datetime frameworks `(DateTime, Class::Date, etc)` do the same.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

```
localtime(time() - 24*60*60)
```

Comment: There is an edge case around DST.  I do not advise this method if you need this to work all of the time.

Comment: The DST edge case can be "worked around", see sample code in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`my $yesterday = time();`
`$yesterday = $yesterday - (24*60*60);`

24 as 24 hours, 60 as 60 minutes in hour and 60 as 60 seconds in minute
`time()` will return actual timestamp, and 24*60*60 will remove seconds for exactly one day
After this simply do:
`localtime($yesterday);`

Comment: A day is not always 86400 seconds, so your method could lead to errors in some cases. Please read Pronin's answer, they give a good example.

Answer (score -1):

```
This is how I do it.

#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX qw(strftime);

$epoc = time();
$epoc = $epoc - 24 * 60 * 60;

$datestring = strftime "%F", localtime($epoc);

print "Yesterday's date is $datestring \n";
```

Comment: This can fail around the beginning of DST for reasons explained in other answers.